# Fill missing values with the most common value in the grouped form

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Could anybody help me with fill missing values with the most common value but grouped form? .Here I want to fill missing value of cylinders columns with the same model of cars.

I tried  this :

```
sh_cars['cylinders']=sh_cars['cylinders'].fillna(sh_cars.groupby('model')['cylinders'].agg(pd.Series.mode))
```

and other ones  but I got everytime error messages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is there are only `NaN`s per some (or all) groups, so error is raised. Possible solution is use custom function with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for return Series with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
data = {'model':['a','a','a','a','b','b','a'], 
        'cylinders':[2,9,9,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}

sh_cars = pd.DataFrame(data) 

f = lambda x: x.mode().iat[0] if x.notna().any() else np.nan
s = sh_cars.groupby('model')['cylinders'].transform(f)
sh_cars['new']=sh_cars['cylinders'].fillna(s)
print (sh_cars)
  model  cylinders  new
0     a        2.0  2.0
1     a        9.0  9.0
2     a        9.0  9.0
3     a        NaN  9.0
4     b        NaN  NaN
5     b        NaN  NaN
6     a        NaN  9.0
```

Replace original column:

```
f = lambda x: x.mode().iat[0] if x.notna().any() else np.nan
s = sh_cars.groupby('model')['cylinders'].transform(f)
sh_cars['cylinders']=sh_cars['cylinders'].fillna(s)
print (sh_cars)
  model  cylinders
0     a        2.0
1     a        9.0
2     a        9.0
3     a        9.0
4     b        NaN
5     b        NaN
6     a        9.0
```

Comment: In addition (my personal use case), you can easily replace the other values (such as 2.0) as well, by simply executing `sh_cars['cylinders'] = s`